# Email to Case requirement

Tags: trigger

Email to Case Trigger:-
Is it possible to auto populate account and contact fields in case when email id is existed in
 contacts

Answer (score 1):

Yes email to case will do this by default but only as long as there is only one matching email address. If you have a duplicate it will not. Custom email fields are supported but the same restriction applies.

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000006526&language=en_US